# Atom stylelint - how to set rules globally?

Tags: global, atom-editor, rules, stylelint, linter

I need to set stylelint globally because it seems like unnecessary work to configure every single project alone, and I am just unable to find such guide anywhere. 
How to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

> it seems like unnecessary work to configure every single project alone

stylelint allows you to [extend](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configuration#extends) an existing configuration.

You can create your configuration file once and then extend that within each of your projects, like so:

```
// .stylelintrc  
{
  "extends": "../my-stylelint-config.js"
}
```

Many users [publish their configurations to npm](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=keywords:stylelint-config), so that they can install them into new projects using `npm install their-config-as-package --save-dev`.

Alternatively, AtomLinter [has a configuration option](https://github.com/AtomLinter/linter-stylelint#configuration) to use the [stylelint standard configuration](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint-config-standard).

Comment: And this is the information I can't find anywhere, where is that code supposed to go?  I am using standard configuration, I know I can extend it with rules, But I don't know where.

Comment: I mean, where is this config file supposed to be located if I want it to be global.
Or if I want just extend the standard one, where to put the code for extending it globally, I am trying package.json but it is ignored.